# Chef aws credential provisioning question

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, provisioning, chef-provisioning

Question about chef provisioning for aws.

The credentials are always passed from a profile? or can you pass them directly from the code?

And the profile file does it require a specific directory or is inside the cookbook?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you refer to [`knife-ec2`](https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2) plugin. if so, then there are few options:

1. use [aws configuration\credentials file](https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2#aws-configuration--credential-files) (aws profile)
2. use [configuration files](https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2#configrb--kniferb-configuration) (aws access\secret key)